# Programmatically open "Turn System Icons On or Off" in a similar way to Cortana search

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, control-panel

I want to programmatically do what is done when I click "Open" in this screenshot, on Windows 10:
[image]

I want to, in order to create a shortcut for this action.

I know I can use the `ms-settings:taskbar` [URI](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-settings.html) to reach the Taskbar section of Windows' Integrated Settings.
That gets me close, but it's not the same as clicking "Open" from Cortana's search results.

How can I?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @harrymc because?

Comment: I listed the reasons below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the old interface:

%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9} \SystemIcons

Same options are available.

Answer (score 1):

Negative answer : Not possible, unless using a keyboard macro product such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The reasons are:

- The Microsoft article
  [ms-settings: URI scheme reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#ms-settings-uri-scheme-reference)
  has no `ms-settings` parameter for this page.
- This page cannot be called by a shortcut as its command-line,
  as found using Process Explorer, does not work from CMD, and only works inside
  the environment of the Settings app:

  ```
  "C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe" -ServerName:microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
  ```